# Styling all TextViews(or custom view) without adding the style attribute to every TextView

Tags: android, xml, coding-style, themes, widget

Is there a way to format all TextViews, Buttons or whatever with a theme ?
Like in CSS when i want to format all a-tags

a{
/*some css here*/
}

I want to do that in android via xml when I'm applying a theme to my application.
Any ideas ?Thanks

http://bartinger.at/

**Update 1.0:**
I want to create a theme that formats the text in all TextViews green and in all EditTexts red. So that i just apply the theme and I never have to worry about the style attribute!

**Update 1.1:**
So I found some that piece of code and I think that's  a good beginning

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextView</item>
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
```

I think thats the answer to my question. But I have another one. I want to write my own ActionBar and wanted to know how I can apply a default style or default attributes (again without adding the style attribute in the layout xml :P )

I have a class

```
public class ActionBar extends LinearLayout{ }
```

and I'm gonna use it like that in my application

```
<at.bartinger.uil.ActionBar>....</at.bartinger.uil.ActionBar>
```

The ActionBar should have some default attributes (like height and width) and then adding some custom style attributes which could change from app to app (like background)

Comment: Sorry, no there is not a way to do this.

Comment: i.e. where does the EditText gets it default height from ??

Comment: Thanks for this - your second update works a treat for me. I'm also looking to increase the size of text but I need it for all text, ie list items and edit text. Where did you find the info about textViewStyle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can you can apply a theme to the whole application and then all your textviews will have that style.

Inside the styles.xml file you have to define your CustomTheme

for example:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

you add something like text 
    "android:textStyle="myStyle" and specify the details in Mystyle

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a **style** read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Comment: It was clear from the orignal question that the author already knows that you can apply a style to each element. The question was how to apply a theme to all elements that match a specific type without having to add style attributes to each element declaration in the XML layout files. -1 for not answering the question or even reading it.

Comment: @Camsoft The question was very different back when I answered it. The author has edited it multiple times after I answered it.

Comment: Maybe SO should not allow major edits to questions as changing the question after answers come in is just plain stupid.

Answer (score 0):

for the action abr you should look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

especially at the bottom it explains very well how to style the bar

Comment: No i mean on pre honeycomb devices. I'm writing an  library to simplify the actionbar. and i know there already some libraries, but i decided to write my own. And its unnecessary if its the actionbar. The question is about how to add default attributes to an view that i created