# How to a apply style to all the TextViews I have?

Tags: android, textview, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Styling all TextViews(or custom view) without adding the style attribute to every TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801890/styling-all-textviewsor-custom-view-without-adding-the-style-attribute-to-ever)

I have got lots of `TextView`s in my app. They have various font sizes, colors, etc. I need to apply `android:shadowColor` and `android:shadowRadius` to them to have all of them with shadows. How to do it?

E. g., I can make a style for the `TextView`s with the necessary properties

```
<style name="text_views">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/tv_shadow</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.7</item>
</style>
```

and apply it to each `TextView`. Is it possible to include properties for the shadows to theme of the application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is.

What you need to do is create an

```
<style name="Theme.RedPlanetTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/tv_shadow</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.7</item>
</style>
```

Then in your manifest you would do this.

```
<application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Red Planet App"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RedPlanetTheme" >
```

### This will allow your whole application to inherit your custom theme style.

Edit

If you want to apply to only textview, then we just need to customize the ThemeRedPlanet a bit more.

```
<style name="Theme.RedPlanetTheme" parent="android:Theme">    
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyRedTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyRedTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/tv_shadow</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.7</item>
</style>
```

[I'm using this as example. Steve Pomeroy applys more directly globally themed (set once kinda deal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android)

Comment: Ah yes, You will need to then make some minor modifcation to your Theme.RedPlanetTheme so the style will be used on TextViews only. I will modify my answer

Answer (score 6):

Please add below line into your textview's property, it will solve your problem.

`style="@style/text_views"`

Comment: In this case I would have to add this line to each `TextView` I have.