# Why is my text in TextView not changing colors?

Tags: android, textview

I'm having issue with certain text views that stubbornly won't change color. I'm not sure why it's not working.

I have my color in a `resource/colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FDCDB2</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E2896B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="mainBackground">#F6F5F5</color>
</resources>
```

I've attempted both hardcoding the color in the layout.xml file as well as dynamically setting the color:

```
    descriptionHeader.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

and

```
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
```

notice in the image the text with the brown hue, that is the desired color. "Description", its body, and "Instructions" have decided to just be a light grey

[image]

below is my code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--make whole layout scrollable-->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--nested view can only have one child-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            >

            <!-- main image of the brew method-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/topImageIV"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!--layout for the brew parameteres-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/brew_method_parameters"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <!--layout for the weight-->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <!--top row of the weight includes image-->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <!--weight image icon-->
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/weight_icon_IV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_weight" />

                            <!--weight parameter set dynamically-->
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/TV_servingDose"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:hint="16 g"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!--serving size set dynamically-->
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/TV_servingNumber"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:hint="1 Serving"
                            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!--layout for time requirement-->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <!--top row of time requirement-->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <!--time icon-->
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/timer_icon_IV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />

                            <!--brew time set dynamically-->
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/TV_timer"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:hint="4:00"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <!--brew time label-->
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:text="Brew Time"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!--layout for grind size-->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <!--top row of grind size includes image-->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <!--icon for grind-->
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/grind_icon_IV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_grinder" />

                            <!--grind description set dynamically-->
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/TV_grindSetting"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:hint="@string/grind_size_coarse"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--grind setting description-->
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                            android:text="@string/grind_setting"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--description of brewmethod layout-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/mainBackground"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!--description label-->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description_header_TV"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/brew_method_description"
                        android:paddingStart="16dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <!--description text-->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/brew_method_description_TV"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/bio_aeropress"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:paddingStart="16dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--instructions label-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/mainBackground"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/brew_method_instructions_title_TV"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:hint="@string/brew_method_instructions"
                        android:paddingStart="16dp"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <!--instuctions recyclerview. set using InstructionListAdapter-->
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rvInstructions"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:minHeight="0dp">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_alarm" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe your **android:theme** has some influence on this.

Comment: @statosdotcom I included the `values/styles.xml` in the above edit. The styles don't make a reference to those shades of grey

Comment: Nice, thank you. And your manifest is pointing to **AppTheme**, right? Ok. Then it's time to override your theme to get what you need. Create a theme for your TextView because it seems there is something over your xml prohibiting this to get the desired colors. Maybe hardcoding in your theme you find your way. (long live cofee lovers)

Comment: Can you post your activity code where you would dynamically set values?

Comment: @statosdotcom check my update, I created a style and tried to apply it. Didn't get a change.

Comment: @parkgrrr added the activity to the post

Comment: Don't know if you did the correct way. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13599666/5885018 (sorry this is not too clear for me too!)

Comment: can you share the complete code

Comment: @Manoj Frekzz For the entire project? Would it be appropriate to post that here or just link to my GitHub?

Comment: Ya it'll be good. Share github

Comment: @ManojFrekzz github link is in the question now

Comment: Your project has lot of issues including memoryout.

Comment: @Manoj Frekzz how does that relate to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was going on:

In my text views with the color issue, I was using

`android:hint="@string/brew_method_description`

instead of

`android:text="@string/brew_method_description`

Switching setting the actual text enabled the color change.